# ruby on rails datatype :text render in view

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I try to use scaffolding in rails to build a blog. I save my blog's content as :text.
However, when I see the view. It can only show in one line. It looks not good.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database stores text, not HTML.  In HTML line breaks are ignored unless they are marked up with relevant HTML tags.  For example, a break between two paragraphs should be marked by the end of one `<p>` element and the beginning of another, and a single line break should be represented by a `<br>` tag.

Rails' [`simple_format`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) helper converts text to HTML by replacing line breaks with HTML tags.

So instead of something like this:

```
<p><%= @post.content %></p>
```

You would do this:

```
<%= simple_format @post.content %>
```